# How execute a process from Power Shell script?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to execute a process from a power shell script:

```
$covFiles = Get-ChildItem -Name -Path .\ -Include Cov*.xml
for ($i=0; $i -lt $covFiles.Count; $i++) {
  $covFile = $covFiles[$i]
  $idx = $covFile.IndexOf("_")
  $covPlatform = $covFile.SubString(3, 3)
  $covFilter =  $covPlatform + "_" + $covFile.SubString($idx + 1).TrimEnd(".xml")
  $command = "-f " + $covFile + " -F " + $covFilter
  & codecov $command
}
```

The working directory has files named, for instance:
- `CovEGLOpenGL.Net.Test_net461_x86_Release.xml`
- `CovWGLOpenGL.Net.CoreUI.Test_net461_x64_Release`...

If I echo the command with `& echo $command` it works as expected on my local machine.

But on [AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com), the process outputs:

```
codecov.exe : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
At line:8 char:3
+   & codecov $command
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The filename, d...x is incorrect.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

This leads me to think that there's something wrong with the parameters specification. May it be quoting?

Replacing `codecov` with `echo`, locally outputs:

```
-f CovEGLOpenGL.Net.CoreUI.Test_net461_x64_Release.xml -F EGL_net461_x64_Release
-f CovEGLOpenGL.Net.CoreUI.Test_net461_x86_Release.xml -F EGL_net461_x86_Release
-f CovEGLOpenGL.Net.Test_net35_x64_Release.xml -F EGL_net35_x64_Release
-f CovEGLOpenGL.Net.Test_net35_x86_Release.xml -F EGL_net35_x86_Release
-f CovEGLOpenGL.Net.Test_net461_x64_Release.xml -F EGL_net461_x64_Release
-f CovEGLOpenGL.Net.Test_net461_x86_Release.xml -F EGL_net461_x86_Release
-f CovWGLOpenGL.Net.CoreUI.Test_net461_AnyCPU_Release.xml -F WGL_net461_AnyCPU_Release
-f CovWGLOpenGL.Net.CoreUI.Test_net461_x64_Release.xml -F WGL_net461_x64_Release
-f CovWGLOpenGL.Net.CoreUI.Test_net461_x86_Release.xml -F WGL_net461_x86_Release
-f CovWGLOpenGL.Net.Test_net35_AnyCPU_Release.xml -F WGL_net35_AnyCPU_Release
-f CovWGLOpenGL.Net.Test_net35_x64_Release.xml -F WGL_net35_x64_Release
-f CovWGLOpenGL.Net.Test_net35_x86_Release.xml -F WGL_net35_x86_Release
-f CovWGLOpenGL.Net.Test_net461_AnyCPU_Release.xml -F WGL_net461_AnyCPU_Release
-f CovWGLOpenGL.Net.Test_net461_x64_Release.xml -F WGL_net461_x64_Release
-f CovWGLOpenGL.Net.Test_net461_x86_Release.xml -F WGL_net461_x86_Release
```

Comment: It's a problem with your arguments, not the way you're calling it.  Your error message states as much: `The filename, d...x is incorrect.`

Comment: I'm not sure: echo outputs `-f CovEGLOpenGL.Net.CoreUI.Test_net461_x64_Release.xml -F EGL_net461_x64_Release`, and I have the file `CovEGLOpenGL.Net.CoreUI.Test_net461_x64_Release.xml` (text cut & pasted).

Comment: Try not using relative paths..

Comment: That paths are relative. I'll update the answer to the relative output with echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix the problem you're running into:

```
$covFiles = Get-ChildItem -Filter cov*.xml

ForEach ($File in $covFiles)
{
    $Path = $File.FullName
    $idx = $Path.IndexOf("_")
    $Platform = $Path.Substring(3, 3)
    $Filter = "${Platform}_$($Path.Substring($idx+1).TrimEnd('.xml'))"

    $ArgList = @(
        '-f',"`"$Path`""
        '-F',"`"$Filter`""
    )
    Start-Process -FilePath codecov -ArgumentList $ArgList
}
```

I suspect the problem you are running into is due to relative paths.

Comment: This looks promising but  replacing `codecov` with `echo` does not execute the relative binary. Should I resolve the absolute path also for executable?

Comment: @Luca As a best practice in scripts, I always use dynamic, absolute paths over relative, hard-coded, or PATH paths every time.  Write once, work forever (hopefully)